# The packet not reaching destination when broadcasted with address 255.255.255.255

Tags: networking, network-programming, broadcast

I have a bacnet application which broadcasts a message to all devices connected. When i use the address 10.9.x.255, it works and the device is able to get the response but when i use the global broadcast 255.255.255.255, the packet is not reaching the device it has to reach.

What may be the reason for this? I can use the address 10.9.x.255 but i would like to know the reason behind it.

On a different computer it works with global broadcast address but does not work on a specific computer. both computers running on windows 10.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Broadcasts do not cross routers. Broadcasts should not be used for communications. If you want to communicate with a group of hosts, then you should use multicast (which can be routed if multicast routing is configured). IPv6 doesn't have broadcast, and using broadcast will require a redesign when moving to IPv6 (as all applications should already support IPv6 in 2018).

Comment: If one of our answers solved your question, please consider to accept the respective answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that the device you want to reach is not located in **your local** network?

Just to clarify the difference:

- 255.255.255.255 broadcasts to any IP-Address in **your local** network (called limited broadcast)
- 10.9.X.255 is a directed broadcast, which is send to the network 10.9.X.0 with the network mask 255.255.255.0 and broadcasted there to all participants connected to the respective local network.

Edit: While you seem to be able to send a directed broadcast, many routers disabled directed broadcasts due to the risk of DoS-Attacks (see [RFC 2644 Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2644)).

Answer (score 0):

When you send a packet on Windows to 255.255.255.255, it only transmits out of one network interface.  This is a bug/design flaw in the Windows IPv4 network stack.

If it's working for you on one of your computers, it's likely that you just got lucky that the one interface Windows is sending your packet from is the one you're using.

References:

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/72e7387a-9f2c-4bf4-a004-c89ddde1c8aa/how-to-fix-the-global-broadcast-address-255255255255-behavior-on-windows?forum=w7itpronetworking
- https://github.com/dechamps/WinIPBroadcast